# Should I create 2 tables: first for usernames and passwords, and other for user information like dob, name, etc?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm really sorry if this is some kind of a bad question to ask, but I am really new to designing MySQL database for an online website(PHP + MySQL) of mine where user accounts need to be managed. In an old project, I had seen someone using 2 different tables: First for User account like username, user id, and passwords, and the other table for related data about the user like dob, name, etc.

I'm confused if this has any particular advantage in terms of optimization or helps in scaling the website. I preferred to use one table for both of these. Is that also advisable?

Comment: It makes sense to use 1 table for all user oriented data (pw, dob, id, name) since it's all related data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One table for username, password, email, date of birth, name, adress, etc. is totally correct.

Though I agree with Capitain Skyhawh's logic to separate user_login/user_profile, I would personally put it in the same table since I find it a little useless to have a `1..1` relationship in the database.

If profile was optionnal, I would definitely use 2 table.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases you should use a separate table to store user attributes. The way I typically do this is with a User table and a UserProfile table. The user table typically contains username, password, last login time, etc that's related to logging into the website. The profile typically has things like name, email address, dob, etc.

I can't speak on the optimization part of things but I can speak on the organization side of things. This layout keeps things much cleaner in the long run. If you're sifting through records, it's much easier to have all "login related" things on one side, and "profile related" on another.

It also just smells bad to have everything grouped into one table. How is a user's dob related to their login credentials? They're not, really.

Just put a foreign key field in the UserProfile table back to the User table and lookups are fast.

Comment: the practical difference is that some real people often share a single login identity.  they are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I had to create links such as http://example/username where username could belong to a user or to a business page. A single table couldn't solve the problem since users and business pages didn't have the same properties.

I had to create a table for usernames which had as foreign keys the user_id and page_id and type (whether user or page).